# C++ split string function gives unexpected output

Tags: c++, string, stdvector

```
std::vector<char*> Split(std::string input) {
  std::vector<char*> ret;
  std::istringstream f(input);
  std::string s;
  while (getline(f, s, ' ')) {
    ret.push_back((char*)s.c_str());
  }
  return ret;
}
```

This function is meant to take a string and put each word into a vector. But say I put `ls -l` as the string. It should return a vector with two elements `ls` and `-l`. Instead, it returns a vector with two elements `-l` and `l`. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Each time you read a new string into `s` the old contents is destroyed and the pointer becomes invalid. Not to mention that it also becomes invalid once the function returns the the life-time of `s` ends.

Comment: I can't use std::string because the function I need to pass it to needs an array of char*'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying pointers do not mean copying what is pointed.

It seems you have to copy the strings.

```
#include <cstring> // for strlen() and strcpy()

std::vector<char*> Split(std::string input) {
  std::vector<char*> ret;
  std::istringstream f(input);
  std::string s;
  while (getline(f, s, ' ')) {
    char* buf = new char[strlen(s.c_str()) + 1]; // +1 for terminating null-character
    strcpy(buf, s.c_str());
    ret.push_back(buf);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing pointers to strings in your vector, but the string `s` is destroyed when the function exits. So you are storing pointers to deleted objects.

Use strings instead of pointers. Strings are easy to copy correctly, unlike pointers. Try this

```
std::vector<std::string> Split(std::string input) {
  std::vector<std::string> ret;
  std::istringstream f(input);
  std::string s;
  while (getline(f, s, ' ')) {
    ret.push_back(s);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: For implementation reasons I need to use `char*`

Comment: Well I would examine whether those reasons really are genuine, for instance couldn't you store strings in the vector and then call `string::data()` to get a `char*` from the `string` when you need it. I can understand that you might need `char*` but I'm not seeing why you need `char*` now. But if they are genuine then you need MikeCAT's solution but you get all the trouble that handling raw pointers gives you.

Answer (score 0):

You got your answer from two other answers, but I have another approach for you to split a string (Called `String Tokenization`):

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string text) {
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    std::string temp{};
    for (int i=0; i < text.size(); ++i) {
        if (text[i] != ' ') {
            temp.push_back(text[i]);
            if (i ==  text.size()-1) {
                words.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
        else if (temp.size() != 0) {
            words.push_back(temp);
            temp.clear();
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```